# Vim - Green highlight when moving cursor position

Tags: vim, alma-linux

When moving the cursor, there is a green highlight which follows the path of where ever I move to.

How do I get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: Is this a `gvim` window or pure `vim` in a colorful console window? I suppose the second; then it would be helpful to know the terminal emulator and the shell you use.

Comment: The shell is BASH. When I ```echo $TERM``` I get ```xterm-256color```. I am using the SSH terminal that comes with Devolution Remote Desktop Manager. I've set the emulation type to Xterm but back space does work if I set it to Xterm.

Comment: then that would seem that either that this terminal emulator that devolution remote desktop manager uses isn't compatible with xterm-256color, or simply buggy. Have you tried usingh a different terminal emulator? Many good choices, like gnome-terminal, konsole, xfce-terminal, alacritty…

Comment: Updating Devolution Remote Desktop Manager fixed the problem.